# Doing maths to a subscribed message to public a new one

Tags: ros, imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working with xsense, and I saw that it's reference coordinate is north west up (quite wierd) and that ROS works with east north up, so I have to change the message that publishes my xsense node to the new reference sistem. The thing is that I know how to subscribe a message, and how to publish, but I don't know how to acess the message that I'm subscribin outside the callback function.

What I would like is something like:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensro_msgs/Imu.h>

void message_received(sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& msg){
   ROS_INFO("Received quaternion: (%f, %f, %f, %f)", msg->orientation.x, msg->orientation.y, msg->orientation.z, msg->orientation.w);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv){
   ros::init(argc, argv, "nwu_to_enu");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   ros::NodeHandle pn("~");
   std::string frame_id;

   pn.param("frame_id", frame_id, "gyro_link");
   ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise("imu/data", 10);
   ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("xsens/imu/data", 1000, message_received);

   sensor_msgs::Imu msg_to_publish;

   //from now on the code might not be correct as I don't really know how to do it, that's my question. msg is the one that I have from the callback function and that I need to be able to access outside the callback function.
   msg_to_publish.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
   msg_to_publish.header.frame_id = frame_id.c_str();
   
   msg_to_publish.orientation.x = - msg->quaternion_x(); //I just change the sign as an example, I'll have to see which transform do I need.
   msg_to_publish.orientation.y = - msg->quaternion_y();
   msg_to_publish.orientation.z = - msg->quaternion_z();
   msg_to_publish.orientation.w = - msg->quaternion_w();

   msg_to_publish.angular_velocity.x = msg->gyroscope_x();
   msg_to_publish.angular_velocity.y = msg->gyroscope_y();
   msg_to_publish.angular_velocity.z = msg->gyroscope_z();

   msg_to_publish.linear_acceleration.x = msg->accelerometer_x();
   msg_to_publish.linear_acceleration.y = msg->accelerometer_y();
   msg_to_publish.linear_acceleration.z = msg->accelerometer_z();

   pub.publish(msg_to_publish);
}
```

Thank you for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12907/doing-maths-to-a-subscribed-message-to-public-a-new-one./) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're shadowing the variables `pub` and `sub` in your constructor.  You're then assigning to these local copies, which leads to them being destructed when the constructor for your class is done.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2012-02-08**:
That's right.

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2012-02-07**:
ah ok, i can see now the difference, what I'm doing wrong is ros::Publisher pub = .... instead of pub = ...., isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you want to move the publishing code dealing with the message into the callback function...

BTW: North, West up leads to 0 deg being north.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-06**:
The canonical ROS convention is East, North, Up (ENU) with zero radians being East. The NED aerospace convention (North, East, Down) has zero to the North.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your callback is never called because you have stored your publisher and subscriber in local variables which go out of scope and get destroyed immediately after constructor finishes. Once you put them in the class variables that you defined you should be fine, assuming the topic name is correct.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1